# tensorflow Lite Segmentation fault

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution :CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908
  -TensorFlow version:2.3.0

I try to convert [the tensorflow offical image caption model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning?hl=en) to TFLite model

And Now I have successfully convert the model using `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions`
as following:

```
@tf.function
def evaluate(img_tensor_val):
    temp_input = tf.expand_dims(img_tensor_val, 0)
    img_tensor_val = image_features_extract_model(temp_input)
    img_tensor_val = tf.reshape(img_tensor_val, (img_tensor_val.shape[0], -1, img_tensor_val.shape[3]))
    hidden = decoder.reset_states(batch_size=1)

    features = encoder(img_tensor_val)

    dec_input = tf.expand_dims([tokenizer.word_index['<start>']], 0)
    result = []

    for i in range(max_length):
        predictions, hidden, attention_weights = decoder(dec_input, features, hidden)
        print(predictions.shape)
        # result.append(predictions)
        predicted_id = tf.random.categorical(predictions, 1)[0][0]
        #
        #
        result.append(predicted_id)
        #
        #
        # if predicted_id == 3:
        #     return result
        # # result.append(tf.gather(tokenizer.index_word, predicted_id))
        # #
        # # if tf.gather(tokenizer.index_word, predicted_id) == '<end>':
        # #     return result
        #
        dec_input = tf.expand_dims([predicted_id], 0)
    return result

export_dir = "./"
tflite_enc_input = ''
ckpt.f = evaluate
to_save = evaluate.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(299, 299, 3),dtype=tf.dtypes.float32))

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([to_save])
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
                                       tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

And I Visualize the converted_model.tflite by [Netorn:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CXCJHVauGiccFpW8itIPUX4kgbnpCgLj/view?usp=sharing)
But when I invoke the interpreter the problem came:
**LOG:**

```
2020-10-03 12:11:24.049222: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-10-03 12:11:30.184705: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-10-03 12:11:30.213363: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:af:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 31.72GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-10-03 12:11:30.213414: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-10-03 12:11:30.219666: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.223018: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.224419: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.227861: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.230195: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.236320: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-10-03 12:11:30.239374: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-10-03 12:11:30.239829: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-10-03 12:11:30.248265: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 2600000000 Hz
2020-10-03 12:11:30.249524: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5615faa7fa90 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-03 12:11:30.249552: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-10-03 12:11:30.381691: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5615faaec0c0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-03 12:11:30.381734: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, Compute Capability 7.0
2020-10-03 12:11:30.383860: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:af:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 31.72GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-10-03 12:11:30.383900: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-10-03 12:11:30.383930: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.383944: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.383959: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.383973: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.383987: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:30.384002: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-10-03 12:11:30.387738: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-10-03 12:11:30.387786: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-10-03 12:11:31.156790: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-10-03 12:11:31.156840: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-10-03 12:11:31.156853: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-10-03 12:11:31.160006: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 30098 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:af:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
**(299, 299, 3)**
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite delegate for select TF ops.
2020-10-03 12:11:31.760387: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:af:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 31.72GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-10-03 12:11:31.760470: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-10-03 12:11:31.760523: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:31.760551: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:31.760577: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:31.760601: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:31.760625: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-10-03 12:11:31.760647: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-10-03 12:11:31.763282: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-10-03 12:11:31.763329: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-10-03 12:11:31.763346: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-10-03 12:11:31.763360: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-10-03 12:11:31.766083: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 30098 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:af:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
**INFO: TfLiteFlexDelegate delegate: 51 nodes delegated out of 2014 nodes with 51 partitions.**

**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**
```

**The invoke of Interpreter**

```
def load_image(image_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (299,299))
    img = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input(img)
    return img, image_path

image = load_image('./test.jpg')[0]
print(image.shape)


interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='./converted_model.tflite')
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], image)
interpreter.invoke()

raw_prediction = interpreter.tensor(
    interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['index'])()
print(raw_prediction)
```

Please tell me what 's the problem of the program?What's the meaning of 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' ?

Comment: A segmentation fault usually means a severe error in the program running. (To be exact, it means an unallowed access to a memory region not belongig to it.) Nevertheless, the root problem may also be somewhere else, not in tensorflow itself, but in libraries or drivers it uses. IMHO this has nothing to do with your program code but with your version of tensorflow, your GPU driver, operating system libraries or something like that. I'm sorry, this information is quite vague, but Segementation Fault is also a quite generic error. Perhaps try and upgrade your GPU drivers as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

After I change the GPU I use to CPU, the program is now correct.But I don't know the Why the the`raw_prediction=291` .But In the `evaluation` function, the return is a `list[]`.How can this be?